# Unplugging the device via ADB: "can't find service"

Tags: android, adb, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-doze, android-doze-and-standby

I have to test how my app behaves in doze mode. According to [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html#testing_doze), I first must make the device think it's unplugged by entering the following command in the terminal:

```
$ adb shell dumpsys battery unplug
```

However, nothing happens and it logs:

> Can't find service: battery

What should I do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no *battery* service as the log points out (this may be device specific).

Enter the following command to find existing battery related services:

```
$ adb shell service list | grep battery
```

it will result in something like this

```
$ adb shell service list | grep battery
88      batterymanager: [android.app.IBatteryService]
107     batterystats: [com.android.internal.app.IBatteryStats]
114     batteryproperties: [android.os.IBatteryPropertiesRegistrar]
```

It makes sense that to manage the battery, you should use the *batterymanager*.

```
$ adb shell dumpsys batterymanager
```

outputs (in case the usb charged is plugged)

```
Current Battery Service state:
  (UPDATES STOPPED -- use 'reset' to restart)
  AC powered: false
  USB powered: true
```

then, when you type

```
$ adb shell dumpsys batterymanager unplug
```

and run the previous command again, it outputs

```
Current Battery Service state:
  (UPDATES STOPPED -- use 'reset' to restart)
  AC powered: false
  USB powered: false
```

Which validates that you should use the *batterymanager* service instead of *battery*.