# Some ADB shell commands only work via ADB and not in terminal emulator

Tags: android, shell, adb

Not a duplicate question or at least I couldn't find anything about this

So I've been getting into ADB and the ADB shell but I don't always have access to a PC so I got a terminal emulator from the play store and some commands don't work via ADB shell

Example: dumpsys battery

Output: can't find service: battery

The command works in ADB shell but not in their terminal emulator. Other dumpsys services work
Why is this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39162535/1778421

Comment: I check to see if there was their service battery using service list and battery was a service but when I do dumpsys battery. Service battery can't be found